# TightVNC and Vista yields "VNC server closed connection"

Tags: windows-vista, vnc, vncserver, tightvnc, ultravnc

I have forwarded the port 5900 for TightVNC. I have TightVNC 2.0 Beta4 installed on my Windows Vista machine.

I then try to connect from an Arch Linux box:

```
[earlz@earlzarch ~]$ vncviewer somehost::5900
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Performing standard VNC authentication
Password:
Authentication successful
vncviewer: VNC server closed connection
[earlz@earlzarch ~]$ vncviewer --help
TightVNC Viewer version 1.3.10
```

What is wrong here? I thought that TightVNC 2.0 fixed the [Vista bug](https://serverfault.com/questions/47571/tightvnc-on-windows-server-2008-disconnects-client-after-login) with VNC servers? Is there any additional configuration I needed?

**Update**
I've tried from my LAN connecting with the TightVNC beta4 client and it yields an "IPv4 Error". I then tried uninstalling the TightVNC server and installing UltraVNC. When connecting to UltraVNC with TightVNC viewer, I get the same exact error. When connecting to UltraVNC with UltraVNC's own client I get "connection closed: server running as application".

I have absolutely no idea why I would have so much trouble getting a simple VNC server running. I am running 64bit Windows Vista, have no firewall installed(and Windows Firewall disabled)

Comment: Post your config

Comment: Have you tried using the Beta 4 Windows client?

Comment: @stuk No I have not.. @Dais it's safe to assume it is the complete defaults. I haven't done any configuration except for setting passwords after installing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem, RealVNC.

I had to install it for some reason a few months ago to get the viewer. Apparently it doesn't ask or anything if you want to also install the server, so it did. The (non-working) RealVNC server hence listened on all the ports instead of TightVNC or UltraVNC.

Disabled the RealVNC server service and fixed all my problems

Comment: For the record: RealVNC's viewer installer is now separate, so you can install it easily without the server.